# メモリの二重解放について

Tags: c++

c++の勉強を最近始めた者です。

返り値を2つ返したいと思いメンバ関数内でクラスポインタを宣言、newして
それをそのまま返り値として使っていますが、deleteする場所がなくこういう場合
にどうしたら良いのかをお聞きしたいです。
クラスポインタを返り値の型として以下のような使い方をしています。
例)
■B.h

```
class B
{
  public:
   float num;
   float vt;
  public:
  void clear(){ num = vt = 0; }
}
```

■A.h
'#'pragma once
'#'include "B.h"

```
class A
{
 private:
   B* value;
 public:
   B* cul(float b);
   B* cul2(float c);
};
```

■A.cpp

'#'include "A.h"

```
 A::A()
{
  value = new B;
}

 A::~A()
{
  delete value;
}

 B* A::cul(float b)
{
   // 引数を使って計算
    value->num = b * 2; 
    value->vt= b * 3;

    return value;
}

B* A::cul2(float c)
{
    // 引数を使って計算
    value->num = c * 5; 
    value->vt = c / 3;

    return value;
}
```

というようなコードとなっています。ビルドもとおり、実行できるのですが
exeを閉じようとすると次のようなエラーが出ます

Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

とでます。二重でdeleteしているという意味のようですが、デストラクタでしか
deleteをしていないのに何故このようなエラーとなるのでしょうか？
また、メンバ関数内でnewしてという方法も考えたのですが返り値として返したいので
deleteする場所がなく実施できませんでした。
c++について勉強中の身のため、質問の仕方が分かりにくくて
申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「B value;」は「B *value;」の間違いではないですか？
「value = new A;」は「value = new B;」の間違いではないですか？
ソースコードを貼り付けるときは、正確にコピペしてください。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。
soramimiさんの言われるように正しくは
B* value;
value = new B;の間違いです。訂正しておきます。

Comment: 指摘された箇所だけではなく全体を書き直してください。コンストラクターに`()`が付いていませんし、`cul2()`がメンバー関数になっていませんし、メンバー名が`B::vt`と`B::time`と不定ですし、そこらじゅう間違いだらけです。

Comment: 重ね重ね失礼いたしました。再度コード訂正いたしました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

挙げられたソースコードが構文上も、メンバー名も間違っていますが、少なくとも二重deleteは行っていません。実際のコードに問題があるか、もしくは挙げられていない呼び出し部分に問題があるはずです。

---

ちなみに

```
B A::cul(float b){
    return { b * 2, b * 3 };

    // 古いコンパイラーの場合は以下記述で
    B b;
    b.num = b * 2;
    b.vt = b * 3;
    return b;
}
```

とポインターでなく`B`自身を返してはどうでしょうか？ `new`しない以上、`delete`は不要になります。

Comment: sayuriさん、いただきましたコメントを元にコードを書き直してみたところ問題なく動きました。分かりにくい質問でも意図を汲み取って丁寧にお答えいただきありがとうございました。
そして、 return { b * 2, b * 3 };といった返し方もあるのですね、とても勉強になりました。